# How to query MongoDB for the id of a document and then use that id in a new query using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to query MongoDB for the _id of one document and then use that _id in a query for another document that has that id in one of its fields.

I'm having trouble with converting the id to a format that the MongoCollection.find method will allow.

Right now, the _id that comes back in the first query looks like this:

```
Document{{_id=4be67619-9a9b-f550-be1b-6086e7038c86,...}}
```

In my code I am doing this:

```
Document mongoDoc = null;
UUID customerId = null;
BasicDBObject mongoQuery = new BasicDBObject();
```

first query gets the _id and in the cursor object I am capturing the _id to a UUID object like this:

```
while(cur.hasNext()) {
               mongoDoc = cur.next();
               customerId = (UUID) mongoDoc.get("_id");
           }
```

The second query looks like this:

```
mongoQuery.put("CustomerId", new ObjectId(customerId.toString()));
```

But when I run the query, I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid hexadecimal representation of an ObjectId: [4be67619-9a9b-f550-be1b-6086e7038c86]
at org.bson.types.ObjectId.parseHexString(ObjectId.java:550)
at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(ObjectId.java:240)
at ngm.java.automation.MongoDbMethodsUnitTest.main(MongoDbMethodsUnitTest.java:61)
```

A working mongo shell query looks like this(I got this value by right clicking the _id value from the first query and choosing copy document):

```
db.Customer.find({ 
"CustomerId" : BinData(3, "UPWbmhl25kuGjAPnhmAbvg==")
});
```

And Studio 3T says the Java version should look like:

```
query.append("CustomerId", new Binary((byte) 3, new byte[] { 80, -11, -101, -102, 25, 118, -26, 75, -122, -116, 3, -25, -122, 96, 27, -66 }));
```

But I'm not sure how to convert a UUID to Binary 3, nor am I sure if that is really the right thing to do in order for this to work.

What is the proper way to do this in Java ?

Comment: Something like `customerId =  new Binary((byte) 3, mongoDoc.get("_id").getBytes());`

Comment: It turns out MongoCollection.find method will allow a UUID object and works just fine. I forgot to change the Collection variable to point to the Collection that actually has the data I am interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out MongoCollection.find method will allow a UUID object and works just fine. I forgot to change the Collection variable to point to the Collection that actually has the data I am interested in.